# CListCtrl. When double click ALWAYS receive NM_CLICK + NM_DBLCLK

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015, double-click, clistctrl

When I press double click with the mouse, I always get two messages `NM_CLICK` and then `NM_DBLCLK`. Why?

Do you know how can I differentiate between both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I press double click with the mouse, I always get two messages NM_CLICK and then NM_DBLCLK. Why?

Short answer: Because the system doesn't implement a time machine.

When you click with the mouse, the system generates an `NM_CLICK` notification, since it doesn't know yet, whether this is the start of a double-click sequence or not. This allows applications to respond to mouse click events immediately, without waiting for the double-click timeout to expire.

To discern between single and double-clicks, you have to postpone your `NM_CLICK` handling, until you know, it's not part of an `NM_DBLCLK` sequence. To do so, set a timer in the `NM_CLICK` handler, and kill the timer from the `NM_DBLCLK`. When the timer expires, you know that there is no `NM_DBLCLK` trailing, and you can proceed to handle the single click.

The following should give you an idea, how to implement this:

```
enum TimerId {
    TimerId_ListCtrlDblClk = 1
};


BOOL CMyDialog::OnNotify( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult ) {
    const NMHDR& hdr = *(const NMHDR*)lParam;
    switch ( hdr.code ) {
    case NM_CLICK:
        SetTimer( TimerId_ListCtrlDblClk, ::GetDoubleClickTime(), nullptr );
        *pResult = 0;
        return TRUE;

    case NM_DBLCLK:
        KillTimer( TimerId_ListCtrlDblClk );
        // Handle double-clicks here.
        *pResult = 0;
        return TRUE;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return CDialogEx::OnNotify( wParam, lParam, pResult );
}

void CMyDialog::OnTimer( UINT_PTR nIDEvent ) {
    if ( nIDEvent == TimerId_ListBoxDblClk ) {
        // If this timer expires, there is no NM_DBLCLK trailing the NM_CLICK.
        // Handle the regular NM_CLICK notification.
    }

    CDialogEx::OnTimer( nIDEvent );
}
```

Comment: Caveat emptor - while this solution does differentiate, make sure your UI behavior is acceptable for single click behavior (i.e. does your UI appear slow).  Remember that the "double click" delay is user-configurable in the Windows mouse configuration, so it could be longer than what you are testing on your machine with your settings.  Note: normally, the default behavior of a single click is acceptable, or inconsequential (and most times desired) when it comes before a double-click (e.g. you WANT the item that was double clicked to be selected, which occurs during the single click handler).

Comment: @franji1: *"the 'double click' delay is user-configurable in the Windows mouse configuration, so it could be longer than what you are testing"* - that's the reason why the code calls [`GetDoubleClickTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646258.aspx), which is the correct timeout value for any user configuration.